# Why can't I inject 2 EJB's into 2 different managed beans that inject each other?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, java-ee-6

ContactsBean

```
   @Named(value = "contactsBean")
@SessionScoped
public class ContactsBean implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    ContactsFacade contactsEJB;
    private List<Contacts> contacts = new ArrayList<Contacts>();
    @Inject
    DetailsBean detailsBean;
```

Details Bean

```
    @Named(value = "detailsBean")
@RequestScoped
public class DetailsBean {

    @EJB
    ContactsFacade contactsEJB;
    private Contacts detailsContact = new Contacts();
```

I can't do this.  Whenever I called the EJB in details bean it throws EJB exception and this.

> Bean Validation constraint(s) violated
>   while executing Automatic Bean
>   Validation on callback
>   event:'prePersist'

Any ideas guys?  Thanks

## **UPDATE**

Ok so I found out it seems that using a requestScoped bean is causing this problem.  Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection takes place directly after the construction of the bean. A session scoped bean is constructed only once per session. The session scope is broader than the request scope. There can be multiple requests inside one session. The injector wouldn't know which request scoped one it has to inject when there are multiple requests at the moment. There may even be no request at all.

To inject the one in the other, the acceptor has to be of the same or a more narrow scope than the injected object. Injecting a session scoped bean in a request scoped bean will just work. I'd suggest that you take this route instead.

---

Unrelated to the concrete problem, I'd also suggest to rethink the EJB approach as well. Do you really need to put the *same* `@EJB` on two beans which are aware about each other already? I'd suggest to remove the `ContactsFacade` from the `DetailsBean` and just let the `DetailsBean` delegate the job to the `ContactsBean`.

Comment: It's still odd though.  I can't inject an EJB into a RequestScoped bean.  I took everything out of the picture.  Soon as I change to it to SessionScoped it works.  Does this have something to do with Stateless and Stateful EJB's?  Thanks.

Comment: Might be related to CDI. I'm not sure how that works. I work with `javax.faces.bean` annotations only. But why don't you just inject it in `ContactsBean` only and let the `DetailsBean` delegate the job to `ContactsBean` or grab the `ContactsFacade` by a getter of `ContactsBean`?

Comment: I'll try that in a few.  The main problem is I really need a requestScoped bean and I'm stuck with sessionScoped at this point.  I thought the javax.faces.bean is being deprecated eventually and it's going to the other annotations?  I read an article a little while back about it.

Comment: Deprecated? Nonsense. This was newly introduced with Java EE 6 as well. You can use either JSF2 annotations or JEE6 CDI annotations. The advantage of using JSF2 annotations is that your JSF2 app is able to run on pure JSP/Servlet containers without CDI such as Apache Tomcat. The advantage of JEE6 CDI is that you can interweave it with other frameworks supporting it like Spring, Hibernate, etc on a JEE6 container such as Glassfish.

Comment: I figured out the whole time that it was throwing the EJB exception because the entity I was trying to update was null.  I'm guessing it was null because of the request scope and it wasn't remembering it's state.

Answer (score 1):

ContactsBean is session-scoped, DetailsBean is request-scoped. You can't inject a request-scope bean into a session-scoped bean.

Similarly you can't inject a session-scoped bean into a application-scoped, and so on.