# Using EJB injection in a POJO

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, ejb, pojo

I know that injection using the @EJB annotation is only possible in an EJB class, a servlet, or a JSF managed bean, but in the same time I need to have an instance of a some injected business interface in a POJO class, so I thought of doing the following:

in my JSF managed bean

```
@EJB BusinessInterfaceLocal businessInterface;

private void someMethod(){
    PojoInterface pojo = new PojoClass(this.businessInterface);
}
```

and in my POJO class I have this constructor

```
BusinessInterfaceLocal businessInterface;    

public PojoClass(BusinessInterfaceLocal businessInterface){
   this.businessInterface = businessInterface;

   //The following throws a Null Pointer Exception
   this.businessInterface.someMethodCall();
}
```

Shouldn't the above work correctly? but it doesn't, the businessInterface object at the PojoClass is evaluated to null, and thus throwing a null pointer exception.

I was hoping if anyone could point me out, on what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the injection to work normally you need to declare the class with something like @Stateless so the injection can occur.  Can you provide the entire class so we can see?

Comment: The problem is not with the business interface because I can use it elsewhere, and it is indeed annotated with the Stateless annotation and the interface that it implements is annotated with the Local, but the error rises when I try to use it outside managed bean in a plain class

Comment: Where *exactly* is the `NullPointerException` thrown? Is it on the line you say, or somewhere deeper in the stack?

Comment: it's on the line that I'm saying, I debugged it an it turns out that this.businessInterface is evaluated to null

Comment: Injections in POJOs do only work if the POJO is container-managed! This means it must be e.g. instantiated via @Inject! An instantiation with new() is NOT container managed.

Comment: But he is not injecting it, just passing it along in the constructor, right? I'd be interested to know if `this.businessInterface` is `null` in `someMethod`...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**verification**

Is it possible you create the PojoClass before the EJB gets injected. By that I mean, where do you invoke "someMethod"? Is it in the constructor of the managed bean? A variable simply does not lose its referenced value.

You said you could see the BusinessInterfaceLocalbean isn't null in the Managed bean, can you verify you create the Pojo after that check?

**Alternative solutions:**

**solution 1**
You can use the POJO as a stateless bean, I don't see any problems in doing that, unless of course you are trying to use the POJO outside of your EE container, which is, by the looks of it not the case.

Making the POJO stateless would make you able to inject the EJB.

**solution 2**
OR a JNDI lookup, implemented as followed:

```
@Stateless(name="myEJB")
public class MyEJB {

  public void ejbMethod() {
  // business logic
  }

}

public class TestEJB {

  public static void main() {
  MyEJB ejbRef = (MyEJB) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/myEJB");
  ejbRef.ejbMethod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the code you show above, the only way that a `NullPointerException` could be thrown at the line indicated is if the `businessInterface` field in the managed bean is null. References cannot mysteriously become null when passed from one object to another, and the `PojoClass` doesn't do anything which would cause the variable to become null. I suggest you do some debugging or logging to definitively determine the value of the field in the managed bean at the point at which the constructor is called. If it is null, then the problem is with injection into the bean, and is not anything to do with the POJO, and you should fix that.

If the exception being thrown is actually from deeper than the line you show, then this could be a problem with the use of an EJB proxy in the wrong context. As you may know, a reference to an EJB is typically not a reference to the EJB itself, but rather to some sort of proxy which passes method calls on to the EJB; the proxy exists so that the container can step in and do things like start transactions, check authorization, and so on. The proxy may need to call on certain contextual resources to do its work which are available when the EJB is accessed from the managed bean but not, for some non-obvious and twisted reason, from the POJO. The unavailability of those resources could lead to a `NullPointerException`. Now, i think it is highly unlikely that simply passing a reference from a managed bean to a POJO would get you into that situation; this would only happen if you did something like accessing the managed bean from a different thread. So, it's probably not this!

Comment: With the code you've shown, that cannot happen. Check your assumptions.

Comment: If you may allow me to further investigate this problem, and I'll get back to you as soon as possible, but I'm pretty sure that what you're saying is the most reasonable of all

Comment: it's an injection problem indeed, I can not use the @EJB injected object in the managed bean

Answer (score 0):

The problem was caused by me trying to use the businessInterface object in the constructor, while the container injects the ejb only after it's done instantiating the managed bean,

reference to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/6537228/1249304

What I did is that I created a method and annotated it with the @PostConstruct annotation, this way after the container is done with instantiating the managed bean, the annotated method gets called and the businessInterface object is no longer null

```
@PostContsruct
public void onInit(){
   //businessInterface is no longer null
   businessInterface.someMethod();
}
```